# 500 Error When Adding a Filter to a REST API Query

Tags: 2010, rest

I'm having an odd error using the SharePoint 2010 REST API. I have a site that has 4 lists with a parent/child relationship. I'm using REST to create an interface for this using Datatables. Suddenly one of the tables has stopped working for the users I have discovered that one of the REST queries now returns a 500 error.

The query works without the filter and I can even see the values that it should be filtering if I remove the filter. This only happens for users that aren't Site Collection Admins which leads me to believe it is a permissions issue but the users all have the correct permissions and can access all of the items so I'm stumped.

Comment: Can you Post the REST api call URL?, I got similar issue in one of my SharePoint online site and I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue in my tenant after an update from MSFT. The Query used to work for all users,But worked only for Site Collection Admins after the update. The issue in my case was having an empty Where Condition in my Caml Query

```
<View><Where></Where><OrderBy>........</OrderBy></View>
```

I removed the Empty Where Condition and it started working, May be you are having the same issue with the REST call, you might be passing an empty value for '$filter' in Url.